# To print perfect numbers below 10 in Python 3

Tags: python-3.5

I am  unable to figure out whats wrong in the code and why 6 is not displayed as a perfect number.

following is my code for printing perfect numbers below 10:

```
    s=0
    for j in range(10):
        for i in range(1,j):
            if j%i==0: 
                s=s+i      #for summing up the factors
        if j==s:
            print(j,'is a perfect number')
        else:
            print(j,'is not a perfect number')
```

Output is :
0 is a perfect number
1 is not a perfect number
2 is not a perfect number
3 is not a perfect number
4 is not a perfect number
5 is not a perfect number
6 is not a perfect number
7 is not a perfect number
8 is not a perfect number
9 is not a perfect number

Comment: `s` is always growing: `s = s + i`. So `s` can never be `0` again. Perhaps you need to reset `s` at the start of each iteration?

Comment: @IonicSolutions Thank you!!...  i Should have have thought more :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you were not resetting s for every integer.

```
for j in range(10):
    s=0
    for i in range(1,j):
        if j%i==0: 
            s=s+i      #for summing up the factors
    if j==s:
        print(j,'is a perfect number')
    else:
        print(j,'is not a perfect number')
```

(0, 'is a perfect number')
(1, 'is not a perfect number')
(2, 'is not a perfect number')
(3, 'is not a perfect number')
(4, 'is not a perfect number')
(5, 'is not a perfect number')
(6, 'is a perfect number')
(7, 'is not a perfect number')
(8, 'is not a perfect number')
(9, 'is not a perfect number')

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset sum to be 0 in the outermost for loop:

```
for j in range(10):
    s=0
    for i in range(1,j):
        if j%i==0: 
            s=s+i      #for summing up the factors
    if j==s:
        print(j,'is a perfect number')
    else:
        print(j,'is not a perfect number')
```

This prints the output:

0 is a perfect number
1 is not a perfect number
2 is not a perfect number
3 is not a perfect number
4 is not a perfect number
5 is not a perfect number
6 is a perfect number
7 is not a perfect number
8 is not a perfect number
9 is not a perfect number